# Laravel 5.2 - Getting 500 error when connecting with CSRF disabled

Tags: angularjs, laravel, debian

I am having an issue where I'm getting a 500 internal error when connecting to my Laravel API.

I had my site originally on GoDaddy using *example.com* as the main site and *api.example.com* as the api, but then decided to move it to Google Cloud Platform. I went ahead and set up an instance in the Google Compute Engine using Debian 8. I am using ISPConfig 3 to do all my server stuff. I have my site and my api in two separate repos on Github. I went my server directory to */var/www/example.com/web* and cloned my main site into it. Since this create a folder within the root directory of my site, I also went into the vhost and set the default directory to point to the new cloned directory.

I then created another site with ISPConfig for my api and went into the DNS and created a A record and pointed it to the same IP as my main site. I then went into */var/www/api.example.com/web* and cloned my api's repo into it, just like my main site. I went into the vhost for my api and pointed the default directory to my new cloned directory.

I can go to example.com just fine, but when I try to log in (this is the first point an api call is made), I get a 500 internal error.

I'm not using CORS and I never have because I use my own JSON web tokens, therefore my CORS is turned off.

Any ideas on how to fix the 500 error?

**EDIT**

Formatting

**Edit 2**

These are the last two lines in the error log for apache:

```
[Sat Sep 24 21:17:17.095798 2016] [core:crit] [pid 17588] (13)Permission denied:  AH00529: /var/www/api.example.com/web/api/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

[Sat Sep 24 21:17:17.095875 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 17588]  AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/api.example.com/web/error/403.html, referer: http://example.com/login
```

I'm not sure why it's throwing this .htaccess error. It's the .htaccess that Laravel automatically created.

Comment: Error 500 is provided by Laravel or by server itself? If by Laravel check error files in storage/logs if by server check apache error.log

Comment: Ok, so I edited the post with the last two lines of the apache error log. It seems to be a .htaccess issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors says what is your problem: `Permission denied:  AH00529: /var/www/api.example.com/web/api/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable`

Make htaccess readable using chmod command:

```
chmod 644 /var/www/api.example.com/web/api/public/.htaccess
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627084/permission-denied-var-www-abc-htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htacces) answers if this not help

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that but now I'm getting an "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. I have CORS disabled in Laravel and this was working on GoDaddy when I had it on there.