# After making wordpress files live, all images showing broken, even image exist in that path

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, broken-image

I have been trying to resolve one issue regarding broken image in WordPress website. Things what I have covered or you need to know to find out this issue are:

1. On localhost all images were fine
2. Problem came when I uploaded all files over live server.
3. I have updated all links into database using bunch of MySql scripts
4. I played with permalinks too but that didn't work for me
5. Website link is http://bukkl.in/ and I am using it as an Add-On Domain
6. My root htaccess file's code is:

```
    

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

7. I checked upload directory's permission. uploads folder has 755 permission and files inside this uploads folder has 644 permission.
8. Images which are broken does really exist. For example: http://bukkl.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/SampleLogo.png
9. WordPress 4.7.3 running Insperia theme.

Please suggest best possible solution for the same.

Comment: Looks like the server could not find the file. Read the server error/access log to know more.

Comment: @Panther Thanks for the help. I checked error log. There is a problem related to accessing that image (Permission issue).

Below is the error message:

`[Tue Apr 18 16:03:04 2017] [crit] [client 59.98.168.196] (13)Permission denied: /home/iamabxiz/public_html/bukkl.in/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://bukkl.in/

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627084/permission-denied-var-www-abc-htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htacces`. can you check those answers ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it is working. However, I need to reupload lots of images due to other reason

Answer (score 0):

It could be a database problem where the images keep the localhost address.

Try duplicator plugIn:

Comment: I already did that using MySql query. If that is the problem then localhost link should come. Which is not possible in this case.