# Wordpress Images are broken

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, broken-image

My wordpress was working fine,then suddenly my images are not displaying anymore. They appear as broken images. I have disabled plugins, changed theme, changed file permissions but it did solved my issue.
[image: Network error]
[image: Example of image not loading]

Server error Log

```
    [Thu May 11 17:02:42 2017] [crit] [client 96.43.225.68] [host afaccra.org] (13)Permission denied: /homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, 
    [Thu May 11 17:02:42 2017] [crit] [client 96.43.225.68] [host afaccra.org] (13)Permission denied: /homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, 
    [Thu May 11 17:02:42 2017] [crit] [client 96.43.225.68] [host afaccra.org] (13)Permission denied: /homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, 
    [Thu May 11 17:02:42 2017] [crit] [client 96.43.225.68] [host afaccra.org] (13)Permission denied: /homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, 
[Thu May 11 19:45:06 2017] [error] [client 197.234.219.17] [host afaccra.org] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" aborted: read failed, referer: http://afaccra.org/wp-admin/tools.php?page=regenerate-thumbnails
[Thu May 11 19:45:06 2017] [error] [client 197.234.219.17] [host afaccra.org] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/homez.47/afaccraons/www/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", referer: http://afaccra.org/wp-admin/tools.php?page=regenerate-thumbnails
```

I am really don'tknow what to do again. Any workaround this issue?

Comment: Have you tried installing and running this tool: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ ?

That has cleared up this issue for me in the past.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. but still not working

Comment: When you right click and inspect the element on the front page, what is the src of the img tag?

Comment: This is the src: http://afaccra.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/facebook-favicon-e1494476966900.png

Comment: Looks like there is a permissions error with your .htaccess file in your uploads directory.  Can you delete it and replace it with a clean version from a fresh version of wordpress.  You can download a fresh version from wordpress.org

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627084/permission-denied-var-www-abc-htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htacces

Comment: I was finally able to work it out. but the issue is that it works well for some hours and then start the same thing again. Have fixed it for about 3times but still come back to same thing. When I used Yandex browser everything display well but with other browsers it doesn't display well.

Answer (score 0):

First check to upload images in media library it is visible or not.
if it is not visible then try these commands.

Also check the htaccess file is readable by apache:
chmod 644 /var/www/abc/.htaccess

And then the directory it's in is readable and executable:
chmod 755 /var/www/abc/

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue. You will need to make sure that the user executing the script has read permission for all the folders & files in the paths. This should not take more than half an hour, just make sure that you do not give too much permission to the folders (for instance a guest should not be able to access them). Also, make sure that the paths are correct.

Comment: I was finally able to work it out. but the issue is that it works well for some hours and then start the same thing again. Have fixed it for about 3times but still come back to same thing. When I used Yandex browser everything display well but with other browsers it doesn't display well.

Comment: @hermeshabib maybe the images were cached under Yandex browser. This periocity smells like a cron job. Check out the cron jobs of your server, in particular those which manage your files. There is a great chance that you will need to change a setting or to modify a script to make sure it generates the necessary permissions. You might be using a plugin which does this, it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

If changing permission of file or folder via CHMOD didn't work, try to change or add permission of user/group using chown command. Contact your hosting tech support if you have no access via SSH to do this stuff.

Comment: I have contacted them 2days ago. And they have not answered since. Don't know what to do again.